# What is the norm of the translation obtained from recoverPose always 1?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am using opencv to estimate the relative position of a stereo pair. I do so by calculating the essential matrix, decomposing it, then performing a chirality check. The latter steps are wrapped up in opencv's `recoverPose` API.

Mat E, R, t, mask;

```
E = findEssentialMat(points1, points2, focal, pp, RANSAC, 0.999, 1.0, mask);
recoverPose(E, points1, points2, R, t, focal, pp, mask);
```

The focal length I give to both methods is greater than 1. My question is, why is the norm of the translation vector I get back always equal to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this can be found in the documentation for `decomposeEssentialMat`.

> By decomposing E, you can only get the direction of the translation, so the function returns unit t.

Comment: Any tips (or sample code) on how to get the magnitude? The same unit vector t could be returned when the camera moves 1mm or 1km.